# Matrix operator is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking at a matrix operator in which $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by $T(x,y) = (x, -y)$. So its basis is $ \mathcal{M}(T) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

How do I show that $T$ is self-adjoint? I understand the definition is $T=T^*$. I seem to be able to understand it better when the operator is not on matrix... How would I show this?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* An operator is self-adjoint iff its matrix is self-adjoint. The adjoint of a matrix is its conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\mathcal{M}(T)=\mathcal{M}(T)^t$, hence $\mathcal{M}(T)$ is symmetric, thus $T$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Can you tell me why if it's symmetric, it means $T$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: $\langle v,Tw\rangle =v^t\mathcal{M}(T)w=(\mathcal{M}(T)^t v)^t w=(\mathcal{M}(T) v)^t w=\langle Tv,w\rangle$

Comment: Thanks so much!